# VM-Ware Workstation Backup onto remote server

Tags: virtual-machine, backup, vmware

My Setup is the following, a host Windows 10 machine with 2 Linux VMs running on VMware Workstation. Further I have access to a Backup server but only through the host machine not through the Linux VMs.

Now my ideal solution, but I don't really know how to achieve this, would be to utilize the snapshot function of VMware. Both VMs reside on a fast SSD (e.g. `D:\VM_workingfolder\`) and I don't want to waste the SSDs space with snapshots. My Idea is to create a full snapshot on a HDD in the windows 10 machine and then whenever a incremental snapshot of a VM is created it references this full and the subsequent incremental snapshots and saves it to this folder (e.g. `F:\VM_backup\`)
The `F:\VM_backup\` would subsequently be backuped to a remote server by the windows 10 backup tool.

Now when I need to rebuild a VM I would rebuild it from `F:\VM_backup\` into `D:\VM_workingfolder\` and in case of a catastrophic data lose I would rebuild `F:\VM_backup\` from the remote backup first.

Is something like this possible to do with VMware Workstation? Because when ever I tried I could only kind of move the Workingfolder with the result of the Intial VM image residing on an SSD and the incremental snapshots on another Drive. Creating a mess ...

The other option I looked at, I found in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/515476/incremental-differential-backup-of-vmware-workstation-vm). I would create backups from inside the VMs with `rsnapshot` and save them to `F:\VM_backup\`. This would be less convenient and I'm not sure if not something funky will happen, when I then let this folder be backuped via Windows backup to the remote server. For example will I be able to rebuild the VMs home folder from this.